# How do I connect an accelerometer (GY-521) to a SparkFun Thing Dev (ESP8266)?

Tags: esp8266, accelerometer

All of the wiring diagrams I've found for wiring up a GY-521 accelerometer to an Arduino have looked something like this:

[image]

I've read in several places that it needs to be connected to `A4` and `A5`. I want to connect one to a SparkFun ThingDev, which unfortunately only has a single analog input:

[image]

Is this possible?

I only need it for a very simple application (finding out if a machine is vibrating or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A4 and A5 on the Arduino double as the I2C pins SDA and SCL.  You are communicating with I2C, not analog.

The ESP8266 doesn't have I2C in hardware, but there is a software-based I2C implementation which can work on any pins.  The pinout you show has I2C labeled on pins 2 and 14. While you *can* use those you could use any two pins of your choosing.

Note that I2C on the ESP8266 has a slightly different begin function:

```
Wire.begin(2, 14);
```

That is where the pins you want to use are assigned - in this case, pin 2 for SDA and pin 14 for SCL.

Comment: default Wire pins in pins_arduino.h for this Thing are 2 and 14. so Wire.begin() is ok